# Unable to upgrade elastic search from 5 to 6

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run the upgrade assistant in order to upgrade ElasticSearch from 5 to 6, however I am hitting the following error:

```
Deprecated script security settings changes
This issue must be resolved to upgrade. Read Documentation
Details: [node[instance-0000000093] used these script-security settings:[script.inline, script.stored, script.file, script.engine.painless.stored, script.engine.painless.file, script.engine.expression.stored, script.engine.expression.file, script.engine.mustache.inline, script.engine.mustache.stored, script.engine.mustache.file]]
```

I have looked over the settings and our Kibana config and cannot find any references to any scrips being used.

Has anyone else run into a similar issue and how did you solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share what you get when running the following commands: `GET _cluster/settings?include_defaults=true` and `GET _nodes?flat_settings=true`

Comment: Ahh I can see `"script.inline": "true",` when I run `GET _nodes?flat_settings=true`. Do you know where these are set as I cannot see these in our deployed config?

Comment: Have you checked in `elasticsearch.yml`?

Comment: We use a managed cluster, would I still have this file?

Comment: AWS or Elastic Cloud?

Comment: Managed by Elastic Cloud

Comment: Then when editing your deployment, you can check if you have anything in the "User setting overrides" section.

Comment: Nothing under "User Settings Overrides" but I did find that `Enable all inline scripts (Not recommended)` is selected under `Manage Plugins and Settings`, however, as per the documentation this is correct - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-upgrading-v6.html